# How do I hide an element if flash has not been detected in React JSX

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to hide an element if Flash is not detected in the browser. let's say that it looks something like this. I am in React and using JSX.

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  // Some code here

  render() {
    // some code here

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>I am going to show no matter if flash is detected or not</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>I am not going to show if flash has not been detected</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { flashSupported: false }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //check flash is supported here
    this.setState({ flashSupported: true })
  }

  render() {
    // some code here
    const { flashSupported } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
          <div>
            <span>I am going to show no matter if flash is detected or not</span>
          </div>
          {
            flashSupported && (
            <div>
              <span>I am not going to show if flash has not been detected</span>
            </div>)
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Replace the `({ flashSupported: true })` to real flash detect code.

**Updated in 4.25**

If the result of script is true, then, flash is supported.(pasted from https://gist.github.com/getify/675496)

```
((typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") || (window.ActiveXObject && (new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")) != false))
```

Comment: Hey David, thanks for that. perhaps I should've more precise in my question. I am actually wondering how I would know if flash is supported. It looks like you have it in CDM which makes sense. however, what is the actual code or plugin..